# What is the first Pokemon game where you can access the pokedex during battles?

Tags: pokemon-series

[Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9dex) says absolutely nothing at what times you access the pokedex. It is a point of unbelieveable difference from the anime- nearly in every battle that Ash has he accesses the pokedex. You can't do it Pokemon Emerald. What was the first pokemon game where you could access the pokedex?

Answer (score 4):

No one from the main series, as far as I remember. Because that's not how the games work. You have to encounter or fight the Pokemon to receive information about it (unless you received it by gift/trade). There's no way to access the Pokedex while battling, also because there's no option in the menu, you can only: fight, change Pokemon, use an item or flee.

The closest one could be *Pokemon Legends: Arceus*, that allows you to check the Pokedex while approaching the Pokemon. Then you can decide to catch it or throw a Pokeball and start a battle.

Comment: "fight the Pokemon to receive information "- could that be its pokedex entry that you already received from capturing that pokemon.

Comment: Also can you can get your party pokemon's pokedex entries?

Comment: If you obtained the Pokemon as a gift or trade, yes, you already have its pokedex page filled